# How to display live data from REST API with SignalR?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, signalr

I have REST APIs that return new data every couple minutes. How to display the new data without making the user to the refresh the browser every time?
This is what I have so far.

AppController.cs

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string[] day = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"};
    List<API> results = new List<API>();
    for (var i = 0; i < day.Length; i++)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://api.example.com/values/d=" + day[i]);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var responseContent = response.Content;

        results.Add(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<API>(responseContent));
    }

    return View(results);
}
```

APIHub.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRAPI.Hubs
{
    public class APIHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendData(   )
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync(    );
        }
    }
}
```

index.cshtml

```
@model Site.Models.API

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Live data</title>
</head>

<body>
<div><h3>Data: <h3></div>
<div class="APIDataResult" id="APIDataResult>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.APIdata)</div>
<script>
        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                                    .withUrl('/APIHub')
                                    .build();
        connection.on({        });
        connection.start(   )
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to make a business/technical decision about whether you want to use polling (client/JS polling every couple of mins) or pushing (controller pushing every couple of mins). Once you have made that decision, either use a timer with JS or in controller with c#. There should be samples on how to do timers for both online.

Comment: @CodingYoshi So I will have a timer in controller that refresh every couple minutes, then I will push the new data through the SignalR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to do this from the controller, here is an example to show you how. In this example, the controller broadcasts a humanized string to all clients every 1 second. The humanized string will contain the length of time internet has been around for. Some of the code below is using fluent API for DateTime etc. so don't let that confuse you. The idea remains the same.

```
public class UptimeHub : Hub
{
}
public class BackgroundUptimeServerTimer : IRegisteredObject
{
    private readonly DateTime _internetBirthDate = On.October.The29th.In(1969);
    private readonly IHubContext _uptimeHub;
    private Timer _timer;


    public BackgroundUptimeServerTimer()
    {
        _uptimeHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<UptimeHub>();

        StartTimer();
    }
    private void StartTimer()
    {
        var delayStartby = 2.Seconds();
        var repeatEvery = 1.Seconds();

        _timer = new Timer(BroadcastUptimeToClients, null, delayStartby, repeatEvery);
    }
    private void BroadcastUptimeToClients(object state)
    {
        TimeSpan uptime = DateTime.Now - _internetBirthDate;

        _uptimeHub.Clients.All.internetUpTime(uptime.Humanize(5));
    }

    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        _timer.Dispose();

        HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
    }
}
```

I have borrowed this code from an article and the full instructions are available [here](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Using-Server-Side-Timers-and-SignalR-in-ASPNET-MVC-Applications). Don't forget to register the `BackgroundUptimeServerTimer` as shown in the article.